# Restrict access to S3 static website that uses API Gateway as a proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have an S3 bucket that acts as a static website and I am using API Gateway to distribute traffic to it.  I understand CloudFront is a better option here, but please do not suggest it.  It is not an option, due to reasons I won't go into.

I am accomplishing my solution by configuring a {proxy+} resource.  Image below:

[image]

**I would like to only allow access to the S3 website from the API Gateway proxy resource.**  Is there a way I can provide an execution role to the proxy resource, similarly to how you can provide an execution role to a resource to runs a lambda function? Lambda execution role example below:

[image]

The integration request portion of the proxy resource doesn't seem to have an execution role:

[image]

Or is there a way I can assign a role to the entire API Gateway to provide it the right to access the S3 bucket?

Other things I have tried:

1. Editing the bucket policy to only allow traffic from the API gateway service:

   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Id": "apiGatewayOnly",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "apiGW",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": {
           "Service": ["api-gateway-amazonaws.com"] 
       },
               "Action": "s3:GetObject",
               "Resource": "http://test-proxy-bucket-01.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/*"
           }
       ]
   }
2. Editing the bucket policy to only allow traffic from API Gateway's URL:

   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Id": "http referer policy example",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": "*",
               "Action": "s3:GetObject",
               "Resource": "http://test-proxy-bucket-01.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/*",
               "Condition": {
                   "StringLike": {
                       "aws:Referer": [
                           "https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod/*",
                           "http://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod*"
                       ]
                   }
               }
           }
       ]
   }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a private S3 bucket
2. Create an IAM role that can access the bucket. Set the trusted entity/principal who can assume this role to `apigateway.amazonaws.com`
3. Use AWS service integration type and select s3. Set the execution role to the role created in 2

Refer to [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) for more details.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed.  For any who see this post later, the section of the documentation that accomplished what I needed was, "Expose API Methods to Access an Amazon S3 Object in a Bucket" since I not only needed to see buckets, but see the objects inside them.

Comment: One issue I've run into going this route is that this uses the underlying S3 API versus the S3 website which has limitations. For instance, the website path allows you to specify an index/error page to be returned, which can both point to index.html which is great for SPA. For the s3 API, errors return an s3 xml -- this breaks SPA routing using modern browser routing as far as I can tell (the second you reload the page on a nested route, you get back the s3 xml error 404). The only way I could get it to work was with older style hash routing.